# Can carrierwave-crop do JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, crop

I got carrierwave and carrierwave-crop which are working just fine. Now I want the file upload to be executed via JS like this:

1. User selects a photo to upload
2. Form is sent and photo uploaded once selected
3. The `crop` view gets rendered via JS
4. Cropping is submitted via JS
5. Newly cropped photo appears

Is there anyway I can do this with carrierwave-crop? I already added [remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) for JS file upload. All I need now is the proper handling in the controller and js file. Just don't know how to start.

*** EDIT ***

I have managed everything except one thing. This is what happens:
1. User selects a photo which is uploaded via AJAX, file select box closes
2. The crop view is rendered via AJX into a newly created modal window which also appears.

However, the cropping stuff doesn't appear because, I would say, the cropping JS isn't executed.

- Tried to move the JS stuff into the response JS - modal window doesn't show anymore
- Tried to move the JS stuff into the view so it gets executed when loaded - modal window doesn't show anymore.

Anyone has an idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Made some progress, anyone got an idea now?